# How to calc action of operator on functions without diagonalizing the operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, diagonalization, discrete-calculus

I have an hermitian operator
$$
h = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + v(x)
$$
acting on square integrable functions that live in some subspace $V$ of $R$.

If I want a computer to calculate the action of this operator on a known function $f$ I would do the following:

- discretize $V$ into the points $x_i$ such that $\Delta x = x_{i+1} -x_i$ is small.
- calculate and store $f(x_i)$ for all discrete points $x_i$.
- calculate the action of $v(x)$ via $$v(x)f(x) \quad\longrightarrow\quad v(x_i)f(x_i) $$
- calculate the action of $-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ via $$ -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f\right)(x) \quad\longrightarrow\quad -\frac 1 2 \frac{f(x_{i+2}) - 2f(x_{i+1}) + f(x_{i})}{\Delta x^2}  $$

However, how can I calculate the action of the operator
$$
\text {exp}({\text i h t}) = \text{exp}\left(\text i \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + v(x)  \right] t \right)\;,\quad t\in R
$$
on a known function $f$ on a computer?

I know that the standard procedure is to diagonalize $h$ (i.e. find the eigenvalues $\varepsilon_k$ and eigenfunctions $\varphi_k$ of $h$). Then I could write
$$
h = \sum_k \varepsilon_k \, \varphi_k \, \varphi^*_k
$$
and
$$
f(x) = \sum_k c_k \, \varphi_k(x)
$$
such that
$$
\text{exp}(\text i h t)f(x) = \sum_k c_k \, \text{exp}(\varepsilon_k) \, \varphi_k(x)
$$

But I want to avoid the diagonalization since it is expensive.

I also didn't need to diagonalize $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ to let it act on a function!

So is there a clever way to avoid the diagonalization of $h$ in order to let  $\text{exp}(\text i h t)$ act on $f$?

Comment: You're trying to find a numerical method for solving the Schrödinger equation? I'm sure there's plenty of material on that in the internet.

Comment: No, I don't want to solve the Schrödinger equation. I want to let the operator $\text{exp}(iht)$ act on a function $f$ **without** diagonalizing $h$. With this I explicitly mean that I don't want to "solve the Schrödinger equation", i.e. I don' want to diagonalize $h$.

Comment: Since you mentioned discretisation, you might want to take a look at how you can compute the matrix exponential $exp(i \hbar t)$ appropriately, for which there are a few methods around. Maybe [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf) and the included references help?